# Spring Cloud Contract and plain Spring AMQP

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-contract

We are using plain [Spring AMQP](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/) in our spring boot projects.

We want to make sure that our message consumers can test against real messages and avoid to test against static test messages.

Thus our producers could generate message snippets in a test phase that can be picked up by the consumer test to make sure it tests against the latest message version and see if changes in the producer break the consumer.

It seems like [Spring Cloud Contract](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/) does exactly that. So is there a way to integrate spring cloud contract with spring amqp? Any hints in which direction to go would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually we don't support it out of the box but you can set it up yourself. In the autogenerated tests we're using an interface to receive and send messages so
you could implement your own class that uses spring-amqp. The same goes for the consumer side (the stub runner). What you would need to do is to implement and register a bean of 
`org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.MessageVerifier` type for both producer and consumer. This should work cause what we're doing in the autogenerated tests is that we `@Inject MessageVerifier`
so if you register your own bean it will work.

UPDATE:
As @Mathias has mentioned it, the AMQP support is already there in Spring Cloud Contract https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html#_stub_runner_spring_amqp

Comment: thanks Marcin - your hints and looking at one of the generated tests made it click for me - and I think I can now try to implement the integration - seems to be a rather small thing.

Comment: Awesome! Let's see if it works :) Can we mark this as answered?

Comment: In the meantime, I added a spring-amqp integration to spring-cloud-contract. So it now is supported out-of-the-box  https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html#_stub_runner_spring_amqp