# Spring cloud contract - integrating with non - spring endpoint

Tags: spring, rest, cloud, apache-kafka, contract

I have a spring webapp that communicates with external service over kafka. IS it possible to somehow test contract between those services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Spring Cloud Contract supports CDC with messaging. If you're using Spring Cloud Stream - the work to be done is trivial. If not then you'll have to implement your own as presented in this issue - [Spring Cloud Contract and plain Spring AMQP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894480/spring-cloud-contract-and-plain-spring-amqp/39897012?noredirect=1#comment67079895_39897012) . Summing it up it's enough for both consumer and producer to implement a custom `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.MessageVerifier` bean that will be responsible for receiving and sending of messages via Kafka